# PIP/easy_install PIL in Virtualenv vcvarsall.bat error Windows 7

Tags: python, django, windows, python-imaging-library, virtualenv

So I know there's a fair amount of documentation on this already, but I just can't seem to get it to work. I'm deploying a Django app to Heroku, and am trying to install PIL into my virtualenv (a main part of the app requires user uploaded images).

I've tried both

```
easy_install PIL
```

and

pip install PIL

and everyone the installation ends in

```
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat.
```

How can I get PIL into my virtualenv? Can anyone walk me through it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about Windows, but `easy_install PIL` does not work well.
`easy_install pillow` (compatible with setuptools) does the trick.
It will still need compilation if I remember correctly, and then you could have a look there : [Unable to find vcvarsall.bat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)

Answer (score 1):

PIL required make.exe or nmake.exe, you may need to install visual studio. vcvarsall.bat is part of visual c++. Please install binary package from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: ive already installed PIL through that site, how do I install it onto my virtualenv?

Comment: and which version of visual studio should i install? im assuming visual studio express 2012 for web will work?

Comment: downloaded visual studio express 2012 web, no change. still vcvarsall.bat

Comment: If you already install PIL binary for windows, it is no needed to install it again from easy_install. vcvarsall.bat is located PROGRAM FILES / MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO / MSVC / BIN

Answer (score 1):

As stated in other answers Pillow is the way to go since PIP is not compatible with setuptools.

So you may just do:

```
pip install pillow
```

Now, since you are working on windows you may run into compilation issues. You will need to install a gcc compiler in order for this to work. I just ran into this issue and blogged about this [here](http://www.megustaulises.com/2013/07/unable-to-find-vcvarsallbat_9.html).

Answer (score 1):

To install Pillow
For this you need a compiler installed on computer, using Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0 (2008) Express Edition (Free). You need this c++ compiler for pillow to install. 
Install from here

```
http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/5/4/A54BADB6-9C3F-478D-8657-93B3FC9FE62D/vcsetup.exe
```

open cmd prompt and enter the following

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Tools\vsvars32.bat"
```

this updates the PATH variable (no need for registry hacks, even in a virtualenv).

Because of firewall difficulties I usually pip install from a local directory

```
pip install -e c:\django\test_virtualenv\Pillow
```

Pillow must be the correction version for your O/S and computer architecture.